# How to calculate the monthly change and plot it as barchar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two given arrays, one filled with datetimes and the other with some values.
These arrays are plotted as a curve in a chart whit matplotlib.
Now I have to calculate the monthly change (difference between the first and last value of every month) and plot it as barchar.
I know how to plot barcharts, but I don't know how to calculate the values with python and put them to new arrays, so that i can plot them.

the vals and the dates array has the same size, and in vals[x] is the value for dates[x]. Also the datetimes in the date array are in ascending order.

Here is a small example, how I plot the values. There are only a few values as example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

# only exampledata, there are approx. 5000 values per day
vals = [1,2,3,6,7,3]
dates =[ datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-01-01T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
         datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-01-02T15:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
         datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-01-31T23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),

         datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-12-01T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
         datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-12-15T15:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
         datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-12-31T23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
       ]


ax.plot_date(dates, vals, ls='-',marker='',markevery=10000)
plt.grid(b=True, which='both', color='0.85',linestyle='-')

plt._show()
```

The expected values to show for that data were:

```
Jan 2
Feb 0
Mar 0
Apr 0
May 0
Jun 0
Jul 0
Aug 0
Sep 0
Oct 0
Nov 0
Dec -3
```

Comment: can you tell me how expected values came ?

Comment: in Jan first value was 1 and last was 3 so 3-1=2. in Dec first value was 6 and last value was 3, so 3-6=-3. For Feb to Nov there was no data in the example, so 0 for these months.

Comment: from vals = [1,2,3,6,7,3] values how can u say that 6 is for Dec ? Can you be more specific

Comment: in vals[x] is the value for dates[x]. mathplotlib requires two arrays (one for the x and one for the y position) to plot.

Answer (score 1):

The following example is based on my best understanding of the question and all comments, if you don't mind using `pandas`. Key steps are:

1. Sort the data to make sure the first and last values of every month are in order
2. Group data by month
3. With in each group (month), apply `last - first`
4. Use an initial DataFrame with monthly change all 0 and update it with results from the previous step
5. Optional. Change data index into abbreviated month name

Here is the code:

```
import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

vals = [1,2,3,6,7,3]
dates =[datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-01-01T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'), 
        datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-01-02T15:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'), 
        datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-01-31T23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'), 

        datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-12-01T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'), 
        datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-12-15T15:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'), 
        datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-12-31T23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
       ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=vals, index=dates)
gdf = df.sort_index().groupby(df.index.month).apply(lambda g: g.iloc[-1] - g.iloc[0])
mchange = pd.DataFrame([0] * 12, index=list(range(1,13)))
mchange.update(gdf)
mchange.index = pd.to_datetime(mchange.index, format="%m").strftime("%b")

mchange.plot.bar()
plt.legend().remove()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't se how the expected values don't match the example. For January, `3-1 = 2`. For December, `3-6 = -3`

Comment: @VictorC. Sorry, it's my mistake. I missed the comments under OP for setting 0 for month without data. Updated my answer with that requirement.